# How to structure a folder with Java libraries and their source/documentation for IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, setup-project, libraries

Using IDEA 9/10, I don't want to use MVN2 anymore (reasons mostly similar to http://kent.spillner.org/blog/work/2009/11/14/java-build-tools.html), but I enjoy some of the things that it provides. The most important point is having my library management include code and documentation automatically.

Jars are not the problem, because I can just throw a folder at IDEA and tell it that my "jars are there". Is there a way to place docs and source relative to that folder so that javadoc and source get detected by IDEA automatically?

(I don't want to check in ipr/iml any more, that just led to constant merge conflicts for us.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature at the moment, you always have to attach sources and documentation manually if your project is not managed by Maven.

Comment: Actually this seems to be sad but true. Life without maven would be a lot more predictable… ;)